# Create object within class definition

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

I want to crate an instance of `ClassB` inside `ClassA`, and assign it to variable `@test3`.

This is my code:

```
module A
  module B
    class ClassA < Hash
      @test1 = Hash.new()
      @test2 = Object.new()
      @test3 = A::B::ClassB.new()

      def initialize(_name, _config = {})
        puts _name
        puts _config
        super()
      end
    end

    class ClassB < Hash
      def initialize(_config = {}, _parent = nil)
        puts _config
        puts _parent
        super()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is possible to set `@test3` within the `initialize` method, but I have reasons not to do so. `@test1` and `@test2` work, but I get an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant A::B::ClassB
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Where is `ClassC`?

Comment: sorry - the error shows unintialized constant A::B::ClassB - i corrected the initial post - my fault

Comment: Can you elaborate on _i have reasons_? Why do you define both classes in one file? What are the reasons to use class variables instead of instance variables? What do you try to archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your ruby interpreter parses your file sequentially, so that when it reaches the `@test3` definition, `ClassB` is still not declared. 
If you can do so, the issue can be fixed by defining `ClassB` before `ClassA`, so that `classB` is defined when defining `@test3`:

```
module A
  module B
    class ClassB < Hash
      def initialize(_config = {}, _parent = nil)
        puts _config
        puts _parent
        super()
      end
    end

    class ClassA < Hash
      @test1 = Hash.new()
      @test2 = Object.new()
      @test3 = A::B::ClassB.new()

      def initialize(_name, _config = {})
        puts _name
        puts _config
        super()
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Small follow-up, if `@test` etc were instance variables, for example declared in the `initialize` method, then the classes could be defined in any order as long as there were no calls to `A.new` before `B` was defined. This may not be correct for the OP though.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ClassB` before defining it. If you switch the order of `ClassA` and `ClassB` your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby interpreter execute codes line by line, including inside class definition, you should keep this idea in mind. when ruby interpreter encounter `@test3 = A::B::ClassB.new()`, ClassB havn't been defined, this is why you get the NameError. to eliminate this error, you should move the definition of ClassB to the front of ClassA.